Getting 'insufficient access rights on cross-reference id' error for guest user when cancelling the request and trying to remove approval process
I have a site guest user, when he rejects or cancel the request then the approval process on the ARM_Task__c should have to be recalled, but it won't happen because on the ARM_Task__c we can give only read and create access to this user this let to the error cross ref id as site guest user tries to make an update
    public without sharing class WithdrawOpenApprovalProcessFuture {
   @future
   public static void withdrawOpenApprovalProcess(List<Id> uarIds){
    System.debug('uarIds---<' + uarIds);
    List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest> requests = new List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest>();
    List<Id> armTaskIds = new List<Id>();
    List<ARM_Task__c> armTasksList = new List<ARM_Task__c>([SELECT Id FROM ARM_Task__c WHERE User_Access_Request__c IN:uarIds]);
    system.debug('arm tasks--'+armTasksList);
    //AccessRequestSettings__c accReqSettings = AccessRequestSettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
    for (ARM_Task__c arm : armTasksList ){
        armTaskIds.add(arm.Id);
        system.debug('arm recs'+armTaskIds);
    }
    system.debug('armTaskIds--'+armTaskIds);
    //OriginalActorId
    if (!armTaskIds.isEmpty()){
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> piwi = [SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: armTaskIds WITH SYSTEM_MODE];
        system.debug('piwi--'+piwi);
        String newOwner='';
        if(piwi.size() > 0){ 
            for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem piwiToUpdate : piwi){
                Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
                req.setAction('Removed');       
                req.setWorkitemId(piwiToUpdate.Id);
                //req.OriginalActorId = '0051a0000018exVAAQ';
                requests.add(req);    
            }
            
            try {
                List<Approval.ProcessResult> processResults = Approval.process(requests, true);
                System.debug('processResults-->' + processResults);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Exception while processing requests: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
            
        }
    }
}

}

